# Root folder structure different depending on where you download

Tags: magento2, layout, folder

I'm brand new to Magento and I have gone straight to M2. I had some initial issues getting M2 up and running and worked through a number of different solutions. What I have noticed is that depending on where/how you download M2 the root folder structure is different. e.g. If you pull from GitHub the app folder is:
root/app/code, design, etc, i18n (which is what I expect according to the training videos).
However if you download M2 with Sample Data (yoga shop) the structure is:
root/app/design, etc
The code folder is in
root/update/app/code

I have also tried downloading some other themes and the code folder seems to also be in the 'update' folder.

Can someone please help to clear this up as I have created a module and it works fine the GitHub version but I don't know where to put it in the other versions, I'm assuming the Vendor folder but 'ass-u-me' is not good!

Thanks

[image: Magento 2 Git hub version]

[image: Magento 2 Download version]